# Wigner rotation for massive particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, rotation

In Weinberg's QFT book pg. 68-69, he stated that the little group element $W(\Lambda,p)$ (the Wigner rotation) for massive particles is $$W(\Lambda,p)=L^{-1}(\Lambda p) \Lambda L(p).$$
He said that when ${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu$ is an arbitrary three dimensional rotation $\mathscr{R}$, the Wigner rotation becomes
$$W(\mathscr{R},p)=R(\mathscr{R}\hat{\textbf{p}})R(\theta)R^{-1}(\hat{\textbf{p}})=\mathscr{R}.$$

I have trouble understanding why $R(\mathscr{R}\hat{\textbf{p}})R(\theta)R^{-1}(\hat{\textbf{p}})=\mathscr{R}$.

My understanding is that the operation $R(\mathscr{R}\hat{\textbf{p}})R(\theta)R^{-1}(\hat{\textbf{p}})$ first takes the axis that $\hat{\textbf{p}}$ lies on into the $z$-axis, then rotates by $\theta$ around the new $z$-axis and lastly take the $z$-axis onto the axis that $\mathscr{R}\hat{\textbf{p}}$ lies on. These three steps combined looks like a mess. How do we know that it is just an arbitrary rotation $\mathscr{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Weinberg describes  $R^{-1}(\mathcal{R}\hat{\textbf{p}}) \mathcal{R}  R(\hat{\textbf{p}}) $ and not $R(\mathcal{R}\hat{\textbf{p}}) \mathcal{R}  R^{-1}(\hat{\textbf{p}}) $.

$R(\hat{\textbf{p}})$ rotates the $z$-axis into the direction of $\hat{\textbf{p}}$, this then gets rotated into a new direction $\mathcal{R}\hat{\textbf{p}}$ and finally $R^{-1}(\mathcal{R}\hat{\textbf{p}})$ rotates a vector from direction $\mathcal{R}\hat{\textbf{p}}$ back to the $z$-axis. In other words these three rotations combine to a rotation around the $z$-axis by a given angle $\theta$.